Unclear point in definition of advantage function in PPO
Please see slide 17 at https://www.syscop.de/files/2023ws/mpcrl/lecture-joschka-pg-and-ac.pdf

Could some expert explain why the terms under expectation (underlined with red) are like that?

It's defined this way so that you can have the above equational relation between the $\eta$-functions of the old and the current policies, as proved in slide 19. And on page 20, the improvement theory regrading the $\eta$-function of the current policy is mentioned possibly referenced from David Silver's Reinforcement Learning lecture as the author claimed.
Bear in  mind that here the $\eta$-function of a policy $\pi_{\theta}$ is the expectation of the accumulated reward under the said (stochastic) policy, and the underlined current policy $\pi_{\theta}$ is required to compute the expectation of the reward term $r(s,a)$ under current policy in your quoted last line as clearly shown in the proof of slide 19. And $s_{t+1} \sim p$ is required to set the distribution of the next transitioned state $s_{t+1}$ following the environment's transition dynamics $p$.
If you have any difficulty in understanding the proof in slide 19, you're welcome to post a new question.
